# Search DOM elements and navigate at them using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to search `DOM elements` matching by some `text`. Wanted to implement feature similar to `Ctrl +F`  . Here is what I tried so far:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("DIV");
elems.forEach(function(e){
     if(e.textContent.includes('Foo Bar')){
          domEl.push(e);
     }
});
```

but `domEl` returns `52 elements` but `Ctrl +F`  showing only `14` records.

Comment: Because textContent returns also the text of the children, so you are pushing into the array also the parents of the element that matches that text

Comment: @Berto99 yes , i suspect too , but how do take care of that.

Comment: Check if the element has children, if not, than us a leaf, and so he is the one that has inside itself the text

Answer (score 2):

Use [NodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) to determine the type of node and ignore anything that isn't a text node. Read the comments:

```js
const getElementsContainingText = (query, selector = '*') =>
  // Get the list of all elements and filter it
  [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)].filter(element =>
    // Get a list of all the current elements childNodes
    [...element.childNodes]
    // Filter out all child nodes that are not plain text
    .filter(ele => ele.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
    // Get the content of the text node
    .map(ele => ele.textContent)
    // Filter out anything that doesn't match the query
    .filter(text => text.includes(query))
    // Return true if there are any matches
    .length > 0
  );

console.log(getElementsContainingText('foo', 'div'));
console.log(getElementsContainingText('bar', 'div'));
```

```html
<div>
  bar
  <div>
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

You could easily combine the two `filter`s and get rid of the `map`, but I did it this way so it was easier to explain in the comments, and to keep the lines short.

Comment: Short and sweet. Is there an easy way to select all visible elements on a page and omit anything else (such as script elements)?

Comment: @Cat - The second parameter will determine what is searched. Use a query selector that omits scripts. If you want to check if the element is visible that's slightly more complicated. If you have jQery you can use `$.is(":visible")`. If not I would recommend searching on SO and ask a new question if you don't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the children of your DIVs to only check #text leafs:

```
const elems = document.querySelectorAll("DIV");
elems.forEach(function(e) {
    for(const node of e.childNodes) {
        if(node.nodeName==="#text"&&node.textContent.includes("Foo Bar")) {
            domE1.push(e);
            return;
        }
```

Keep in mind that this will only select the DIVS that directly contain the searched text:

```
<div id="a">Foo Bar</div>                // a will be selected
<div id="b"><span>Foo Bar</span></div>   // b will NOT be selected
<div id="c"><div id="d">Foo Bar</div></div> // c will NOT be selected, but d will
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution **searches children of a container element recursively to collect matching results** in a `collection` array.

**Each result object has two properties**: the **element** containing the textNode where the match occurred and the **text node** itself. This allows us to later extract whatever information we want about the element (such as its `id` property) and/or about the text node (such as its full text).

```js
const
  myCollection = [],
  searchIn = document.getElementById("container"),
  searchFor = "Stack";

collectMatchingDescendants(searchIn, searchFor, myCollection);
printCollectionInfo();

function collectMatchingDescendants(node, text, collection){
  if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    let children = node.childNodes;
    for (node of children){
      if(node.nodeType == 3 && node.nodeValue.includes(text)){
        const element = node.parentElement;
        const myObject = { element: element, node: node };
        collection.push(myObject);
      }
      else{ collectMatchingDescendants(node, text, collection); }
    }
  }  
}

function printCollectionInfo(){
  for(let obj of myCollection){
    console.log(`${obj.element.id} matched (text: '${obj.node.nodeValue.trim() }')` );
  }
}
```

```css
*{ border: 1px solid lightgrey; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="div1">
    Stack Overflow 1
    <p id="p1">Stack Overflow 2</p>
    <p id="p2">Nothing interesting here</p>
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    Stack Overflow 3
    <p id="p3">Stack Overflow 4
      <span id="span1">Stack Overflow 5</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```